# Remote Access to DC Security Event Full Data

Tags: powershell, security

Issue - Only getting partial data from security event logs.

I am pulling Security events from a 2019 Domain Controller using Powershell. The code works fine on the server and i can see all data (provided Powershell runs elevated). Remote user has been added to the AD "Builtin" folders security group "Event log readers". Remotely i get partial data for the event. i.e. Event->Properties->SyncRoot part of the event is empty remotely. Plus error

`Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord] does not contain a method named 'ToXml'.`

> So how do i enabled a specific remote user to get full access?

Code below, thanks

```
    # On local server use the -Computername and -Credential are not used
    $events = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $dc -Credential $cred -scriptblock {Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']=`'$using:account`']]"}
    foreach ($event in $events)
    {
        # Convert the event to XML            
        $eventXML = [xml]$event.ToXml() # error when used remotely
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're having is not related to permissions but to `Invoke-Command` [deserializing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_output?view=powershell-7.1#deserialized-objects) your object.

> However, the deserialized object is not a live object. It is a snapshot of the object at the time that it was serialized, and it includes properties but no methods.

One way you could avoid this is by converting the logs to `XML` in the remote host:

```
$events = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $dc -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    $logs = Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']=`'$using:account`']]"
    $logs.ForEach({$_.ToXml()})
}

foreach($event in $events)
{
    [xml]$event
}
```

Something similar happens with Jobs:

```
$log = Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -MaxEvents 1
$log.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name               BaseType
-------- -------- ----               --------
True     False    EventLogRecord     System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventRecord
```

```
$log = Start-Job {Get-WinEvent -LogName Application -MaxEvents 1} |
Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

$log.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name               BaseType
-------- -------- ----               --------
True     True     PSObject           System.Object

$log.ToXml()

Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord] does not contain a method named 'ToXml'.
...
...
```

Comment: OK that worked!, now i need to find the way of getting the earlier data from the XML
              $event.TimeCreated;
              $event.Id;
              $ip = ($eventXML.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'IPAddress' }).'#text';